# How to limit text width in <tspan> inside <div>

Tags: css, wordpress

How to limit area text the function "add text" in tshirt design plugin.

```
Code:

<div class="content-inner">

<span class="drag-item ui-draggable ui-resizable drag-item-selected ui-draggable-disabled ui-state-disabled" id="item-0" style="left: 2px; top: 30px; width: 1206px; word-wrap: break-word; height: 27px; z-index: 1; transform: rotate(0rad); border: 1px dashed rgb(68, 68, 68);" aria-disabled="true">

<svg width="1206" height="27" viewBox="-0.046875 0 1206 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g id="0.4042886124895173">
<text fill="#CCCCCC" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="50" y="21" text-anchor="middle" font-size="24px" font-family="arial">

<tspan dy="0" x="50%">gfadsfdasfdsfdsfasfdafasdfadsfadsdsfdsfdsfadsafacdfsdfdsfdsffdsafdsfds</tspan>

</text>
</g>

</svg>
<div class="item-remove-on glyphicons bin" title="Click to remove this item" onclick="design.item.remove(this)"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-rotatable-handle item-rotate-on glyphicons restart ui-draggable"></div>
</span>
</div>
```

I tried these codes css but it did not work.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
width: 100px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can’t be done in CSS. But here are some options:

If you are trying to limit the number of characters in a word, you can use a JavaScript character counter (and some server-side validation).

If you’re instead trying to limit the number of lines to a single line, you’ll have to change all of the whitespace to non-breaking spaces (the HTML entity is `&nbsp;`). That will ensure that the words stick together in one line. A phrase might then look like this: `Hello&nbsp;world!`